# How to Kill and Restart UnityGLView inside Swift

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine

I have integrated Unity3d in native iOS Swift. I can able to call the Start Unity function and it launches the game. But I am unable to kill the process and restart the game again. Suggest some solution for restarting the game.

I had followed the below tutorial to integrate the Unity into native ios.
Link : https://medium.com/@IronEqual/how-to-embed-a-unity-game-into-an-ios-native-swift-app-772a0b65c82

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just reload the scene?

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html